# How to allow comparison between Fixnum and custom class?

Tags: ruby, comparison, operators

I've already used coercion to handle arithmetic operators :

```
class MyCustomClass

  def coerce( other )
    [MyCustomClass.new(other), self]
  end

end
```

Which means I can do:

```
42 + MyCustomClass.new
```

**I'd like to know if a similar mechanism exists** that would allow me to perform comparisons (without monkey patching `Fixnum`) :

```
42 > MyCustomClass.new
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to include [`Comparable`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Comparable.html) and define the `<=>` operator:

```
class MyCustomClass
  include Comparable

  # ...

  def <=>(other)
    # e.g. compare self to fixnum and return -1, 0, 1
  end
end
```

Comment: works for `MyCustomClass.new > 42` but does not seem to work for `42 > MyCustomClass.new`. Maybe i'm doing something wrong ?